# Orbeon customizing set of buttons in Form Builder

Tags: forms, orbeon

Is there some possibility to remove button 'new' from form builder ? I know, that I can customize set of buttons in form runner detail page, but I can't find solution to remove button from form builder. Any ideas ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet. There is [an RFE for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1416).